# Retrieve Value from NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring, atoi

i have a NSString instance ,i want to retrieve value from it and store it into an integer.
This is wat i am doing but its not working.

```
NSString *totalcnt;
char *str = totalcnt;
int a = atoi(str);
```

Help me out.
Thanks

Taimur

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are dealing with Objective-C objects, use Objective-C:

```
int a = [totalcnt intValue];
```

Reference: [`intValue`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/intValue)

---

In your code example, you don't instantiate a NSString but I hope your are doing it in your real code. Otherwise, `totalcnt` is a [wild pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = [totalcnt intValue];
```